# Best way to detect data polarity change from positive to negative?

Tags: python, numpy

I have been trying to figure out the best way to find changes in polarity ( from positive to negative, and vice versa) for a given data set. Basically, I'm looking for the point where the data starts off positive for a while, and then switches to negative for a while. So far I've made some few attempts that seem to give something, but I was wondering if there was a way to being smarter about it. My attempt at solving it so far:

```
Deriv_Data= np.diff(Data) 
zero_crossings = np.where(np.diff(np.signbit(Data)))[0] 
index = []
val = []
for j,val1 in enumerate(Deriv_Data):
    if val1 <= diff_cutoff and j + 1 in zero_crossings:
       index.append([j])
       val.append([val1])
```

This gives me something like this as the result. [image]

The results seem to be points where there is a quick dip, and then returns back to normal.

Comment: Perhaps pull out the outliers first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get your point why don't you just check where the data changes sign?

```
signs = np.sign(data)
places = []
for ii in range(1, len(signs)):
    if signs[ii] != signs[ii-1]:
        places.append(ii)
```

Now `places` contains the index of sing-changes.

`data[places]` should give you the data values.